# Failed to load plugin in Gulp using Eslint

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, gulp, eslint

I added gulp to my asp.net core project.

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var eslint = require("gulp-eslint");

var paths = {
    allScripts: [
        "wwwroot/app/*.js",
        "wwwroot/scripts/**/*.js"
    ]
};

gulp.task("verify-scripts", function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.allScripts)
        .pipe(eslint({
            rules: {
                "consistent-return": 0,
                "quotes": [0, "double", { "allowTemplateLiterals": true }]
            }
        }))
        .pipe(eslint.format());
});
```

But the problem is when I run my task then I have error: `Error: Failed to load plugin react: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react'` but I don't using react, only angularjs.

Anyway I added eslint-plugin-react (npm install eslint-plugin-react --save-dev).

Then after I run task I have error: `Error: Cannot find module 'babel-eslint'` come on......

But I added it...
And then I have error: `Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-defaults/configurations/eslint'`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have indirect dependency to react. Please read following thread on this discussion

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/71

From what I get is you need to remove extra dependencies here. 
Comment by alechp on May 11, 2016 where he mentions the problem and solution is what you are looking for.